# Interrupt Thread when music is playing

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop, interrupt, interrupted-exception

I have some problems to interrupt a thread which plays a mp3 file in the background of the app. I would loop the file playing and stop it when app close.
Here is my Main class :

```
public class Main {

        public static String musicPath = "/loop.mp3";
        public class RunnableMusic implements Runnable{
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("Listen... " + musicPath.replace("/", "").replace(".mp3", "").replace(".wav", ""));
                 while(!musicThread.isInterrupted()){
                    BackgroundMusic.listen(musicPath);
                 }
            }
        }
        public Thread musicThread = new Thread(new RunnableMusic());
        public static void main(String[] args){
            musicThread.start();
        }
        public static closeApp(){
        }
    }
```

And this is my BackgroundMusic class :

```
public class BackgroundMusic{
    public static void listen(String music){
        InputStream file = BackgroundMusic.class.getResourceAsStream(music);
        try {
            InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(file);
            Player playMP3 = new Player(bufferedIn);
            playMP3.play();
            playMP3.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't play music : " + e);
        } 
    }
}
```

When I use musicThread.interrupt() in closeApp() method, nothing happens, and the mp3 file still be played. I tried to insert catch clause with InterruptedException, but Eclipse always underlines it as InterruptedException doesn't exist...

Any idea ?

EDIT : I use Javazoom Player to play mp3 files. And I use JavaSE-1.6 Environment.

Thanks.

Comment: The player should have controls in order to control the media. So, the object that controls the media should be a shared resource. That way you can control the media as you want. Then, when you close the app, you stop the player. Also, the condition that keeps the thread alive should be redesigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the player you're using, but I guess it should be stopped by calling `playMP3.stop()`. At least this is how `MediaPlayer` in JDK 7 is stopped.

Anyway, you're trying to interrupt a thread running `playMP3.play();` which appears to be a blocking method, e.g. it doesn't check it's interrupted state from time to time. As soon as the current track finishes playing, execution should stop after a check at this line:

```
while(!musicThread.isInterrupted()){
```

**UPDATE**

My guess is that you're trying to interrupt your thread which is running this line:

```
 playMP3.play();
```

And this method is a blocking routine, it cannot be interrupted by calling `Thread.interrupt()`. It's just written this way - it doesn't check the interrupted status while playing the music.

So instead of calling

`musicThread.interrupt()`

You should bring your player variable to a higher level and call:

```
 playMP3.close();
```

Which should stop the music according to the docs:

> `public synchronized void close()` - 
>   Cloases this player. Any audio currently playing is stopped
>   immediately.

Comment: Can you describe me more precisely your answer with my example ? I tried to put playMP3.close() after the while like this [link](http://pastebin.com/vT2bkwbw), but there's no change, my file plays well in loop but still playing when the app is closed.

Comment: Updated, I hope this would help.

Comment: Thank you I understand better now, I believed the thread will continue to process even if I put a playMp3.close() in my closeApp() method. But its' not the case, the thread is automatically stopped. ;)